# How to reduce a 2D array in TypeScript to return a 2D array of unique subarrays?

Tags: node.js, typescript, multidimensional-array, types, reduce

I'm trying to reduce my 2D array such that there are no duplicate subarrays. I used the .reduce() method to take care of this, however it appears that my conditional statement doesn't work the way one would imagine.

Please refer to the stdout for some additional clarity. Let me know if you know how to make this work or a possible workaround.

```
const unique = result.reduce<number[][]>((accum, curr) => {
        if (!accum.includes(curr)) {
            console.log('accum:', accum);
            console.log('curr', curr);
            return [...accum, curr];
        }
        else{
            return accum;   
        }
    }, []);

console.log('\nresult', result);
console.log('unique', unique);

/*
stdout:
accum: []
curr [ 0, -1, 1 ]
accum: [ [ 0, -1, 1 ] ]
curr [ 0, -1, 1 ]
accum: [ [ 0, -1, 1 ], [ 0, -1, 1 ] ]
curr [ 2, -1, -1 ]

result [ [ 0, -1, 1 ], [ 0, -1, 1 ], [ 2, -1, -1 ] ]
unique [ [ 0, -1, 1 ], [ 0, -1, 1 ], [ 2, -1, -1 ] ]


desired output:
unique [ [ 0, -1, 1 ], [ 2, -1, -1 ] ]
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Set`. Please keep in mind it wirks only with array of primitive values

```js
const makeUnique = <T extends string | number | symbol>(arr: T[]) => [...new Set(arr)];


const unique2D = [[1, 1, 2], [2, 2, 2, 1], [3, 3, 3]].reduce<number[][]>((acc, elem) =>
  [...acc, makeUnique(elem)]
  , []
)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAWwIYGsCmBVCBLAjgVzTgF44AeAFTjQA8Y0IATKOWAJ2wgHM4AfOCPgQAjNGz6sAniLAAbAHwAKJGzYAuOBQDaAXQCUJeXC0A6MxDQB3OAGU0MZar06A3MHfho8fDgJoATAAiJMZaAIwANHCRcP46UVr%20UUmxUWHxxgDMUdlwmTo6JmxojPggaGSCImK6ukrKICBRaLJoCAbE8sBwxmYmSI1RyOhYeISKLW3O3XAJOsB6QA)

**UPDATE**

```js
const makeUnique = <T extends string | number | symbol>(arr: T[]) => [...new Set(arr)];

type MainType = number[]
const unique2D = (arr: Array<MainType>) =>
  arr.reduce<Array<MainType>>((acc, elem) => [...acc, makeUnique(elem)], [])

const getDublicates = (arr1: Array<MainType>, arr2: MainType) => {
  return arr1.reduce((acc, elem, index) =>
    elem.length === arr2.length && arr2.every(el => elem.includes(el))
      ? [...acc, index]
      : acc
    , [] as MainType)
};


const check = (arr: Array<MainType>) => {
  const dublicates = arr.reduce((acc, elem) => makeUnique([...acc, ...getDublicates(arr, [...elem]).slice(1)]), []);
  return arr.filter((_, index) => !dublicates.includes(index))
};

const result = check(unique2D([[0, -1, 1], [2, -1, -1], [3, 3], [3], [3], [4], [4]]));
```

Comment: I tried ```makeUnique(result)``` and got...
"Argument of type 'number[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(string | number | symbol)[]'."

Comment: Please keep in mind, that if you have array of objects , `Set` will not work

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I am trying to remove duplicate arrays, within the 2D array. Your solution removes duplicate values within an array.

Comment: @Shah I made an update, please try, it removes dublicated from 2D array. Check `unique2D`

Comment: Your solution changes [[1, 1, 2], [2, 2, 2, 1], [3, 3, 3]] to [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3 ] ]

That's awesome! But I am looking for something like this:
[ [ 0, -1, 1 ], [ 0, -1, 1 ], [ 2, -1, -1 ] ] to [ [ 0, -1, 1 ], [ 2, -1, -1 ] ]

Comment: @Shah please take a look an second update

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for the time being. If anyone can solve it with Set or .reduce() please let me know.

```
    const result: number[][] = new Array(); //results obtained later on in code
    
    const Unique: {[key: string]: number} = {}; //store unique results in a hash
    const solution: number[][] = new Array();
    let target;
    
    //remove possible duplicates:
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        let key = JSON.stringify(result[i]);
        if (!Unique[key]) {
            Unique[key] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (let key in Unique) {
        solution.push(JSON.parse(key))
    }
    
    return solution;
```